# Woocommerce custom redirection based on purchased multiple products after payment

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, payment

I use wooCommerce theme and this my working redirect after checkout per product code :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'redirect_product_based', 1 ); 
function redirect_product_based ( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
            foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
                // Add whatever product id you want below here
                if ( $item['product_id'] == 3531 ) {
                    // URL 
                     wp_redirect( 'www...' );
                }
                if ( $item['product_id'] == 35 ) {
                    // URL 
                     wp_redirect( 'www....' );
                }
            }
}
```

Now i want code working for multiple products like :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'redirect_product_based', 1 ); 
function redirect_product_based ( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
            foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
                // Add whatever product id you want below here
                if ( $item['product_id'] == 331, 332, ... ) {
                    // URL 
                     wp_redirect( 'www...' );
                }
                if ( $item['product_id'] == 35, 36, ... ) {
                    // URL 
                     wp_redirect( 'www....' );
                }
            }
}
```

Any help with this to apply for multiple products please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this with as little modification to your working code as possible would be to use [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

Also, please note the use of `exit;` after [`wp_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/). You can see why I added it on this [post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/400525/why-exit-is-needed-after-wp-redirect) and in the docs:

> Note: wp_redirect() does not exit automatically, and should almost always be followed by a call to exit;

Furthermore, if you want to make sure that you always redirect to a page on an allowed host, you should have a look at [`wp_safe_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_safe_redirect/) and replace your `wp_redirect` calls

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'redirect_product_based', 1 ); 
function redirect_product_based ( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        // Add whatever product id you want below here
        if ( in_array($item['product_id'], array(331, 332)) ) {
            // URL 
             wp_redirect( 'www...' );
             exit;
        }
        if ( in_array($item['product_id'], array(35, 36)) ) {
             // URL 
             wp_redirect( 'www....' );
             exit;
        }
    }
}
```